# MYSQL fulltext - What's the right way to get the relevance from one column?

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search

I want to make one column more valuable than others like it's been done in query bellow.[This example](http://www.vionblog.com/mysql-full-text-search-with-multiple-words/)  shows that only one fulltext index is needed And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547542/how-can-i-manipulate-mysql-fulltext-search-relevance-to-make-one-field-more-val/600915#600915)suggests that three fulltext indexes are needed to do the same.

Here is the queries from the first link:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD FULLTEXT(title, sdescription, ldescription)

SELECT *,
MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('+iphone +case +4s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 10 as rel1,
MATCH(`sdescription`) AGAINST ('+iphone +case +4s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 3 as rel2,
MATCH(`ldescription`) AGAINST ('+iphone +case +4s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel3,
FROM products
WHERE MATCH (title, sdescription, ldescription) 
  AGAINST ('+iphone +case +4s' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY (rel1)+(rel2)+(rel3) DESC;
```

I'm confused how many indexes are needed for that, one or three?
I asked this question on stackoverflow but no answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM? or InnoDB?

4 `FULLTEXT` indexes will work in either engine.

You could find out by creating an empty table and running that `SELECT` against it.  It should give you an error if the set of indexes you tried is wrong.  The `ALTER` to add/drop indexes.

Comment: Rick, what I'm not understanding is why more than one indexes  been suggested in that stackoverflow answer? This query is from that stackoverflow answer `SELECT id, keyword, content, MATCH (keyword) AGAINST ('watermelon') AS rel1, MATCH (content) AGAINST ('watermelon') AS rel2 FROM table WHERE MATCH (keyword,content) AGAINST ('watermelon') ORDER BY (rel1*1.5)+(rel2) `
You can see that this query and the query in my question are doing the same thing, "making one column more valuable". Is the answer on stackoverflow wrong?

Comment: I think that MyISAM allowed use of a single 3-column index for `BOOLEAN MODE` for your query, but InnoDB needs 4 separate indexes.  I have made a stab at the differences in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#fulltext).  The answer you saw probably failed to note the Engine.

Comment: thanks @Rick James. I forgot to mention last time that I will use InnoDB. The query I posted in my question uses MYISAM. It's from the first link I posted in my question.